# How to define different CSS transforms without stomping on each other

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

If one class adds a rotation to an element and another class adds a scale, how do I define those in CSS without them stomping on each other.

```
<!-- HTML snippet -->
<div class="class1 class2"></div>

/* CSS snippet */
.class1 { transform:rotate(45deg); }
.class2 { transform:scale(0.5); }
```

In the above example the div would only be scaled because the transform property definition in class2 overrides the one in class one.
How do I get these two different style rules to apply these different transforms?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I believe you will need to do something along the lines of

```
<div class="class1"><span class="class2"></span></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tutspack/dQY2g/)

CSS

```
 .class1 {
        margin-top:100px;
        width:100px;
        height:30px;
        background-color:#000;
        transform:rotate(45deg);
    } .class2 {
         width:100px;
        height:30px;
        background-color:#00f;
        transform:scale(0.5);
    }
```

HTML

```
<div class="class1"></div>

<div class="class2"></div>
```

You might have to use 2 divs or once inside span

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
/* CSS snippet */
.class1 { transform:rotate(45deg); }
.class1.class2 { transform:scale(0.5); }
```

Comment: This would work, but it requires that the CSS style sheet that defines a scale is aware of the CSS style sheet that defines the rotate. Is there no way to define a scale for an element without stomping on other transforms that may have been performed by other CSS libraries? I guess I can use JS to append to the property value of the style rule.

Comment: @JackFlint You can use jquery's addClass('class2') and removeClass('class2') to play to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and works perfect. i think it just needed to add old browsers pre keywords.

```
.class1{-moz-transform: rotate(20deg);
-wibkit-transform: rotate(20deg);
-o-transform: rotate(20deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(20deg)}

.class2{-moz-transform: scale(.5);
-webkit-transform: scale(.5);
-o-transform: scale(.5);
-ms-transform: scale(.5)}
```

Comment: Thanks, Abolfazi, but I am targeting Windows 8, so I don't need to worry about browser compatibility.

Comment: Have you implemented this? I'm sure scale in class2 will override rotate in class1. there result will be just an scale transform.